# How do I avoid this physique? Any exercises I should do/not do?

Tags: exercise

[image]

This is not me. But a LOT of dudes at my gym look like this, and honestly, I want to avoid ending up with a similar physique.

In particular, I feel like there's some disproportionately sized arms versus center body. The chest has some mass to it, but nothing impressive. The waist looks like that of a girls at the beach. It is clear this guy spends most of his time doing bicep curls and shoulder presses.

Am I correct in stating that to NOT end up with this physique, one should focus less on arms, and more on chest + abs?

Comment: What kind of physique *do* you want?

Comment: It looks like this guy has been doing everything right.   What you are seeing is just the natural proportions of his body.  Maybe he could do a lot more chest exercises, but it might not make much difference.

Comment: That's actually a very well proportioned body. As @Chris says, possibly a little bigger chest, but the main problem that I usually see is massive chest/arms at the expense of the back/lower body.

Comment: The shoulder press is perhaps the most important/complete upper body exercise. You should make it a priority. If you think the guy is too skinny, simply eat enough to not be skinny. I get that, I don't think it's a good look for most men, but that's subjective  and trivial to solve, just eat plenty

Comment: Sounds like you answered your own question.. do less arm and shoulder exercises, and more chest, back, and ab exercises

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to fitness.stackexchange!

First of all, **the guy in the picture looks like a beginner, maybe 6 months to a year or working out at best**. So it could be that he isn't doing everything right because of the fact that he is a beginner.

Secondly though, I think he looks fine and is pretty allround. Everybody has strong and weak points, so when you on everything evenly you still might end up with a chest that isn't in proportion with your arms or what ever. This guy has good proportions thought, I don't see the problem. **It certainly doesn't look like he spends most of his time doing biceps or shoulders.**

Thirdly, **you shouldn't focus on what you don't want. You should focus on what you DO want.** We can't tell you what not to do so you don't look like this. We could help you if you stated what you do want.

Comment: Much better than my upcoming answer of "drink beer, eat pizza and become addicted to online gaming" ;)

Comment: @DarkHippo Haha I could include that in my answer if you like x)

Comment: @DarkHippo - Hey, don't be dissing on my workout plan. :)

Comment: @JohnP Haha, I've been working on it myself for several months :D

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends what you’re looking for. A lot of people would strive to have his body style, but I agree that visible abs are generally overrated and not necessary.

Chest development is really tough. I continue to have issues with my chest development and am always dancing a fine line between a shoulder injury and adding weight/reps to my bench. Every time I make progress, I start to feel the onset of something bad in my chest and have to back off. For years I fought having the chest of a 13 year old boy. Now, I have one of a 17 year old boy. And I’m nearly 38.

Most of the people who look like what you’re describing, though, don’t do two particular exercises: squats and deadlifts. Those two exercises virtually guarantee solid mass and they have a particular effect on the upper body that is hard to describe. You HAVE to train those two exercises and consistently add weight to the bar. In order to do that, you’ll have to eat and sleep well enough. But, trust me, you won’t look like that if you do squats and deadlifts. Your chest might still suck though... Mine does. :-)

Comment: In general chest development isn't more tough than any other muscle group, in your case it might be true because of a shoulder injury you mention. I just wouldn't tell beginners that chest development is hard just because thats what you're experiencing. It might put them off based on something that might not be true for them at all. Some people say chest is the easiest thing to grow, others will say back or legs are the easiest. In general, all muscles react the same way, it is just based on your genetics if a certain muscle group is harder to grow.